# React mapping context record to text input

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Firstly I'm new to React and cannot find the answer to my problem.

I want to share the values of a JSON record between several React components, and have those values displayed and editable in a series of text boxes.  I have got my head around the sharing between the components, but...

**PROBLEM: I cannot map the Input Boxes to the values in the Context component properly... Help please**

So I have created a Context component to represent the data I need to store:

**Data Storage:**

```
import { useState, createContext } from 'react'

export const AddressContext = createContext();

export const AddressProvider = (props) => {
    const [address, setAddress] = useState({
        "line1": "1",
        "line2": "2",
        "line3": "3",
        "town": "4",
        "county": "5",
        "postcode": "6",
        "country": "7",
      })

    return (
<AddressContext.Provider value={[address, setAddress]}>
     {props.children}
</AddressContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And then in another component display in input boxes and map values
**Input and display**

```
import {  useContext } from 'react'
// Store for address information
import { AddressContext } from './SPLAddress'


const ShipAddress = () => {
        const [address, setAddress] = useContext(AddressContext) ;

    return (
        <div>
           <h2 >Shipping Address</h2> 

           <form className='add-form'>
           <div className='form-control'>
                        <label>Line 1:</label>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Line1' 
                         defaultValue ={address.line1} 
                         /* onChange={(e) => address.line1 = e.target.value} */
                          /*  onChange={(e) => setAddress(changedRecord => [address, {line1: e.target.value} ]) }  */
                           onChange={(e) => setAddress(changedRecord => [address, {line1: e.target.value} ]) }  
                         />
                </div>

AND SO ON...
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
 
export default ShipAddress
```

As can be seen in the comments I have had several attempts at the onChange events but cannot get the onChange event to alter the appropriate value in the first JSON record.

Also I guess by using `defaultValue ={address.line1}` any change the app makes to the values will not be updated in the UI.  Using `value={address.line1}` locks input.

**APP level**
And at the APP level, we have wrapped the components with the AddressProvider

```
<AddressProvider>
      <SPLSearch searchButton={SPLsearchButton}/>

      {showSearchList &&
              <SPLList lines={lines}  selected={SPLselected}  />
      }
      {!showSearchList &&
              <ShipAddress l />
      }
  </AddressProvider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing so:

```
const ShipAddress = () => {
  const [address, setAddress] = useContext(AddressContext) ;

  return (
    <div>
       <h2>Shipping Address</h2> 

       <form className='add-form'>
        <div className='form-control'>
                <label>Line 1</label>
                <input 
                  value={address.line1} 
                  onChange={e => setAddress(prevAddress => ({
                      ...prevAddress, 
                      line1: e.target.value 
                  }))}
                />
        </div>
       </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: That would add another record.   Loads of examples floating around of adding records to the structure.  This is all about editing the single record.  Sorry

Comment: I am sorry i misunderstood, so i thought you are trying to create an input for every key in your address object and get their values.
I updated the code to create only one input for a key, and state update function for it. Please try this @SamSmith

Comment: And also want to mention what is wrong with your code:
1. In first comment you try to update state directly. THAT IS NOT POSSIBLE IN REACT.
2. In your second and third comments you are trying to update state half way correctly. Your state is an object, but instead of an object you are returning an array from your callback which you passed to setState function.
3. Also in your second and third comment you are getting latest state from the callback but then you are using the address state. Just choose one, either use state directly or the latest state argument from the callback

Comment: Hay that's great thanks so much.   It actually seemed to save the whole event back, but with slight alteration, it worked as I need it.  Have edited the above code.  Great thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Updated my answer. I would appreciate it if you could accept my answer.